# What lumber for window seat frame?

Tags: lumber

I'm making window seat with storage. Do I need 2x4 for the framing or can I use smaller size lumber - eg 1x3?

Comment: No framing at all!  A seat *with storage*  can be made entirely out of 3/4 inch or even 1/2 inch ply or solid boards.  The solid, continuous walls of the storage compartment provide plenty of strength.

Comment: How about some dimensions of the storage seat you're building?